# Gauss-Bonnet Theorem - Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Why is the equality in red true? [image]

$\bf{e}^{'}$ and $\bf{e}^{''}$ form an orthonormal basis of the tangentplane w.r.t $\gamma(s)$, which is unit speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the usual computation of a line integral in terms of a parametrization: Because $\dot u = du/ds$, $du$ becomes $\dot u\,ds$ (and vice versa), and, similarly, $dv$ becomes $\dot v\,ds$.

Comment: Thank you. Never worked with that. I assume that the integral is taken of everything (both terms)?

Comment: Yes, yes. What source is this for differential geometry, out of curiosity?

Comment: We are using Elementary Differential Geometry 2.ED by Andrew Pressley.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. Didn't realize his notation was so classical and clunky :P

Comment: Hehe, well I haven't seen anything else, and apart from that there is alot of theory I'm missing to understand it properly. Just hoping to pass the examn at Friday :)